# how to change the bounding box color in the video output in yolov3 darknet

Tags: google-colaboratory, colorbox, bounding-box, yolo, darknet

I have trained YOLOv3 darknet model on my custom dataset. First I have cloned the `https://github.com/kriyeng/darknet/` repository in google colab and then run the whole code in google colab. But I want to change the color of the bounding boxes in the output video. Please suggest how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in C++ but you can apply it to python as well. Just change the values in Scalar. In the example below it is set to the color red.

```
//Draw a rectangle displaying the bounding box
rectangle(frame, Point(left, top), Point(right, bottom), Scalar(0, 0, 255));
```

Comment: Yo, how to get scalar?

Comment: Scalar is present by default in OpenCV to allow you to pass pixel values. If you're using python I do not think the Scalar type in C++ and Python are the same. You could do the following                                                                                                                                                                                                                             # Create a blank 300x300 black image
image = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.uint8)
# Fill image with red colour (set each pixel to red BGR not RGB)
image[:] = (0, 0, 255)